# Unable to get text with Regex.Match

Tags: c#

I use the code below to get the text before "@yahoo". The results I have not received anything. I had no idea where I was wrong.

```
  /////get text

        string allcode1 = "";
        string GetCode1(ChromeDriver driveryahoo, int timewait = 30)
        {
            string code = "";

            driveryahoo.Url = "https://mail.yahoo.com";

            for (int i = 0; i < timewait; i++)
            {
                code = Regex.Match(driveryahoo.PageSource, ">(\\w)@yahoo<").Groups[1].Value;
                if (code != "" && !allcode1.Contains(code))
                {
                    allcode1 = allcode1 + code + ";";
                    return code;
                }

            }
            return code;
        }
```

Comment: Your regex pattern does not match that Yahoo URL.  What are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: It is "htpps://mail.yahoo.com" I did not get the desired result

Comment: @Navila given that you are trying to extract something from the page, can you share what is the text that you are matching against, and what is the desired output?

Comment: in the url i go there it's text " youmail@yahoo.com ". I want to extract the text " youmail " precedes before @yahoo .